# "TypeError: expected string or buffer" stemming from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from yelp and put it into a .csv file using urllib, beautifulsoup, and pandas. I am getting several errors and I am not sure what to do.

I have reviewed all the similar questions I could find online but none of them seem to be the same issue.

This is what error I get at runtime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sydney/PycharmProjects/yelpdata/venv/yelp.py", line 7, in <module>
page_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
File "/Users/sydney/PycharmProjects/yelpdata/venv/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 310, in __init__
markup, from_encoding, exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)):
File "/Users/sydney/PycharmProjects/yelpdata/venv/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 248, in prepare_markup
exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)
File "/Users/sydney/PycharmProjects/yelpdata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", 
line 395, in __init__
for encoding in self.detector.encodings:
File "/Users/sydney/PycharmProjects/yelpdata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", 
line 278, in encodings
self.markup, self.is_html)
File "/Users/sydney/PycharmProjects/yelpdata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", 
line 343, in find_declared_encoding
declared_encoding_match = xml_re.search(markup, endpos=xml_endpos)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

[This is my python file (linked to GitHub)](https://github.com/sydneyc1/yelpscraping.git)

Comment: What is `source`?

Comment: source = urllib.urlretrieve('https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=Nashville%2C+TN&ns=1')

Comment: Why are you using `urllib.urlretrieve()`?  The purpose of that function is to copy the contents of a url into a local file.

Comment: I think you want `source = urllib.urlopen('myurl').read()` instead.

Comment: I was using url.urlopen but when I did it wouldn't run at all because it said "Import Error: no module named request" but I have the request package installed.

Comment: thanks! that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source needs to be `source = urllib.urlopen('myurl').read()`

Adding .read() will resolve the error